itertools.islice iterate over input even when stop is smaller than start
For a custom container wrapping an iterator, I intended to delegate some of my logic to itertools.islice. One consideration was to avoid unnecessary iterations over the wrapped iterator.
When calling itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop, step) with stop<=start, the result is an empty generator, as expected.
But even though it's not absolutely needed, itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop, step) will always iterate at least start number of times over the iterable.
Test case to repro:
from unittest.mock import Mock
import itertools

iterableMock = Mock()
iterableMock.__iter__ = Mock(return_value=iterableMock)
iterableMock.__next__ = Mock(side_effect=range(10))

iterable = iterableMock
start = 5
stop = 0
step = None

isliceResult = list(itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop, step))
assert isliceResult == []
assert iterableMock.__next__.call_count == 0  # <= FAILS since call_count == 5

Is this behavior:

Expected / by design. We want to skip the elements until start is reached no matter what.
Just a side effect of the current implementation that only impacts the performance of some corner cases.
A potential improvement that can be addressed without concerns.

Documentation can be a bit misleading/misinterpreted on the expected behavior.

elements from the iterable are skipped until start is reached
it stops at the specified position

The suggested "equivalent implementation" and the source code clearly iterate until start-1. stop parameter is only considered subsequently.

"Just a side effect of the current implementation that only impacts the performance of some corner cases." <- this

That looks like a design decision to me. One could imagine a different case where that's exactly what is wanted. You could write your own islice wrapper that works the way you want.

@jsbueno - I'd disagree about it being a side effect. Suppose I have a file iterator. islice guarantees that I consumed lines up to start-1. That's not a corner case or a strictly performance issue.

Indeed - I think the main use case for islice is to skip the first n items. Anyway, I did not refer to that in my answer.

Imagine that you call islice() multiple times over the same iterator. You need to ensure that each one skips over start items so the next call will start at the correct place.

I suggest to use simpler code and show its output. I was unfamiliar with all that Mock stuff and I find it distracting and I suspect I'm not alone.

Consuming elements from the underlying iterator is part of the islice contract, and cannot be optimized out. There's even a recipe in the recipes section of the official itertools docs that relies on empty islices consuming elements:
def consume(iterator, n=None):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is None, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)

However, the contract arose more by historical accident than actual design.
Raymond Hettinger, the person who designed the function and wrote the original docs, did not intend islice to make any promises about the final state of the underlying iterator - not even the promise that the consume recipe relies on. Quoting one of Raymond's posts in a conversation about a similar edge case with step:

Currently, there are no promises or guarantees about the final state
of the iterator.

And their next post in that conversation:

I wrote the tools, the docs, and the tests. If you interpret a "promise" in text, I can assure you it was not intended.  The behavior is undefined because I never defined it. I'm happy to clarify the docs to make that explicit.

As a result of that conversation, the implementation was adjusted to change the behavior in that edge case, and element consumption details were considered defined from then on.
Years later, someone else brought up the start>stop case. Raymond's response includes the following line:

Having islice() always consume at least "start" number of values seems reasonable enough and it is the documented behavior: "If start is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until start is reached. ... If stop is None, then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted, if at all; otherwise, it stops at the specified position."

indicating that they considered consuming start items in the start>stop case to be part of the documented contract.

That argument doesn't really work, since start==stop there.

@nocomment: Any argument that consuming elements is unnecessary for start>stop applies equally to start==stop.

No, the conflict with the quoted "it stops at the specified position" is only a conflict when start>stop.

@nocomment: Ah, that's what you're focusing on. Since the question presents the element consumption as "unnecessary" and approaches things from the perspective of a performance issue, my answer focused on demonstrating that element consumption is part of the islice contract and cannot be optimized out. I suppose I can adjust the answer a bit.

Yeah, the question is specifically about "when stop is smaller than start" (title), so arguing with something where that's not the case is rather meaningless. I myself have used stop=0 sometimes when start was a longer expression than just "n", and I'm looking forward to a real convincing argument. I had a look at the test cases, as I'd take those as showing intention, but I don't think there is any testing this. I see some with start>stop and one that checks iterator state afterwards, but none testing both.

@nocomment: I've adjusted my answer now.

Looks great now. The author of the start>stop issue even said "don't know whether that coincidence is by accident or design", very close to this question. I did interpret the doc like Raymond said there, although I think it can be understood differently (the start part not having priority over the stop part), but Raymond made it clear how it's meant. I'm just puzzled why he said that changing islice to not consuming anything "would incentivize a new and weird idiom for "consume" as islice(it, n, 0)", as that wouldn't even work then. Anyway... Should we delete our comments?

It is just that the implementation does not check before hand if stop is bigger than start.
You can test for it before calling islice, an djust provide an empty iterator in that case:
isliceResult = list(itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop, step) if stop >= start) else ())

(above, the () stand for an empty tuple).
Note that by the very nature of islice, the step argument cannot be negative, so the condition start <= stop suffices for all working cases. If you expect to get valid negative steps, then it will probably be easier to write some custom code than trying to reuse islice for that case.
